# Race Building: Endless legend Broken Lords as PF PCs

Tags: pathfinder-1e, races

I've been thinking of running a Pathfinder game set on Auriga from Endless Legend (For those of you who don't know, it's a 4X by amplitude studios). I was building the various races of the game using the Advanced Race Guide race creation rules, and it was going well until I hit the Broken Lords. To summarize for the people who haven't played EL, the Broken Lords are a once-living race who couldn't adapt to Aurgia's changing climate, so they bound their souls into suits of armor. They are forced to survive by consuming Dust (The particles that make up magic) or the souls of other creatures. There are two main problems I don't know how to fix:

1. The Broken Lords are either constructs or undead, but both traits cost bucketloads of RP
2. I don't know how I would integrate the Dust/soul dependency

How could I properly represent the Broken Lords using the Pathfinder ARG rules?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take a moment to check out the [tour] and the [help] to get an idea of how things work. Your question right now seems like a bit of a request for ideas, which doesn't fit well here. If you could reshape it into a more specific question that would be great.

Comment: It seems like this is an opener for a brainstorming session [where every answer is equally valid](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), which isn't a kind of question we handle here. [Your question might be better suited to a chat room or a traditional forum](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go), as you'll get more helpful feedback on a site intended for open-ended discussion.